# aws aurora custom cluster name through cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have written cloudformation template for aws mysql aurora . cluster and db instance created . but the name of cluster is the combination of name of stack name &  the resource name . for example : cluster name & endpoint 
test-rds-3-test-4tz8fvcilgt5. 
test-rds-3-test-4tz8fvcilgt5.cluster-ro-cr7d6ijxaz7u.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

command :- aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name test-rds-3  --template-body file:///home/mahendra/clodcft/cft-rd.json

i want to create the custom cluster name for example "production test"& it should not be depend on the stack name or resource name . can any please help me on same.

```
  "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
  "Properties": {
    "AvailabilityZones": [
      "us-east-1c",
      "us-east-1d",
      "us-east-1e"
    ],
    "BackupRetentionPeriod": 1,
    "DatabaseName": "test",
    "DBClusterParameterGroupName": "test-parametergroup",
    "DBSubnetGroupName": "test-subnetgroup",
    "Engine": "aurora",
    "EngineVersion": "5.6.10a",
    "MasterUsername": "admin",
    "MasterUserPassword": "adminadmin",
    "Port": 3306,
    "PreferredBackupWindow": "04:00-04:30",
    "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "Mon:05:00-Mon:05:30",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "testrds"
      }
    ],
    "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [ "sg-edcssd199" ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to control the exact name of the cluster? After working with CloudFormation for the past 3 years, I can safely say that you should avoid hardcoded resource names. When you hardcode a resource name that must be unique in a region you make your template usable only once and you prevent update to the resource that requires a replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response . But our requirement  is bit different . this template is regions specified and we are also not planning to use it for any other purpose . do you have any suggestion for same .

Comment: It's definitely not possible. I'd like to here about your requirement because there's a few workaround. You can dynamically provision a Route53 recordset using the attribute "Endpoint.Address" so you could have access the database using a subdomain (ex: testrds.exemple.com). You could also simply add an "Output" to this template with the endpoint address and whatever service that needs it could just get the output of this stack.